# Visual studio error list shows empty results list

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

After fixing errors and rebuilding the error list window still has empty placeholders and a count of zero errors.

[image: VS error list window]

This only goes away after restarting VS

It seems random, some days I dont get the problem at all with the same solution

Trying to open one of the empty errors by clicking on it gives me a "Visual studio has encountered an unexpected error." message.

Its driving me crazy. Cant find any help out there or other people reporting the same problem

Comment: Are you sure this is not caused by some visual studio extension ?

Comment: I've disabled all the extensions I can (only left those that would need to be uninstalled) and still have this issue. I guess that removing all extensions and reverting to a vanilla setup would probably fix this but I like / need my extensions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VS gets crazy many times.

1. Make sure your version is up-to-date,
2. Delete your automatically generated .suo file(s) (resides near the solution file)

Still bad? there might be a corruption or invalidity in a XML file it tries to read or something like that.

3. Try removing temporary files and generated files. Look at this:

   https://www.google.com/?q=visual%20studio%20temp%20files%20location#q=visual+studio+temp+files+location]
4. You can try using VS Command line switches like /Log and /Out. Further more - Add switches to the MSBuild command in your project configuration. Here is the references:

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx
5. Try using SysInternals ProcessMonitor to see What file is opened just before the error occurs.
6. Nothing helped? Reinstall VS completely. do a full Uninstall. I suggest you backup your preferences and tools beforehand. You can do this manually or by signing in to VS with your live ID.

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457348.aspx

Be aware - your extensions should be re-downloaded. and one of them might be the cause for all this suffering

Comment: Tried 1-5 and got a few hours with no problems before the problem recurred, so is suspect its a temp file issue. Reluctant about losing the time it takes to do a reinstall but no other options left after trying @Avram s suggestion.
+1 for the range of options though.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this does the trick, update VisualSVN:

https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/

Comment: I've the latest version - I updated all the out of date extensions in one of the many attempts to resolve this, even disabled it still occurs.

Answer (score 2):

To debug this, you can use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9589139/61883

solved it by:

1. Open two instances of Visual Studio. Open the same project in both.
2. In one instance, goto Debug->Exceptions and enable all the 'Thrown' options to stop at first chance exceptions. This will stop the debugger when the exception is generated.
3. In the same instance, select Debug->Attach to Process, select devenv.exe.
4. In the other instance, open the form to cause the exception
5. With any luck the first instance should stop somewhere that yields a more relevant exception.

Comment: Completely killed my VS install. Good suggestion but after attaching to devenv.exe the debugging instance crashed and now I get MEF errors on every start-up (from core VS components!). 
Going to have to be a wipe clean and start again.

Comment: @Matt sorry to hear it, this solution help me a lot when i have same problems. maybe you need to use devenv.exe /safemode /log  on instance that debugging other instanse.