# Exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Design.ExceptionCollection' was thrown

Tags: c#

I created Custom Control that inherits from BindingNavigator component, in its constructor I use this code:

```
if (!DesignMode)
{
   bindingNavigatorMoveFirstItem.Image = Image.FromFile(Path.GetFullPath("Pictures\\last.png"));
}
```

I use this control in another form and when I try to open the form (in design mode) I get the following error:

> *Exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Design.ExceptionCollection' was thrown.*

what should I do to solve it?

Comment: Well, what's the exception message?

Comment: that's all. I get it in messageBox.

Comment: If it is a message box shown by your IDE, there should be a way to inspect the full properties of the exception.

Comment: check out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579544/system-componentmodel-design-exceptioncollection